# How to take a prop of type function from a top level component and use it in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

So if i have an app something like...

```
const App = ({ onEvent }) => 
    <div>
        <SomeComponent>
            <OtherComponent>
                <DeeplyNestedOtherComponent />
            </OtherComponent>
        </SomeComponent>
    </div>
```

and **`App`** gets rendered like...

```
<div>
    <App onEvent={() => { console.log('event')} } />
</div>
```

**What is the best way to access `onEvent` in a redux action or middleware? Where I don't want to pass it down through multiple levels of props**

i.e in `actions.js`

```
const updateUser = (name, email, description) => dispatch => {
    // How do i get access to this?
    onEvent();

    return dispatch({
        type: "USER_UPDATE",
        payload: {
            name,
            email,
            description,
        },
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions here.

1. How to pass down the handler function without passing it down through props?

   - In `App` add the handler to the context
   - In `DeeplyNestedOtherComponent` get the handler from the context

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

2. Once `DeeplyNestedOtherComponent` has the handler, how to use in the action creator?

   - Pass the handler as a parameter

However, I think it would be better to avoid this completely. Can’t you make `App` react to what the action does (the reducer in truth) using `connect`? This would avoid passing down a handler and also, the action wouldn't need to know that a handler exists.

By the way: I really don’t like the idea of storing the handler itself in the redux store. I like to think of the redux store as a data store; not a code store.

Answer (score 0):

set your function in your redux store and then access it via state in actions:

```
const updateUser = (name, email, description) => (dispatch, getState) => {
     getState().myfunctions.onEvent()
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a correct way to do this, but I had to do something similar recently. My approach was to use one of the `App` component's lifecycle methods to store the function in redux in the state.

for example:

```
// actions.js
const storeEvent = (eventFunc) => dispatch => {
  return dispatch({ type: 'STORE_SOME_EVENT', eventFunc });
};

// reducer
const initialState = { eventFunc: '' };
function someReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action) {
    case 'STORE_SOME_EVENT':
      return {
        eventFunc: action.eventFunc,
      };
  }
}

// component
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // or some other lifecycle
    const { storeEvent, onEvent } = this.props;
    storeEvent(onEvent);
  }
}
```

and pass the storeEvent function as a prop from the redux container.

then you can do this:

```
const updateUser = (name, email, description) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    getState().eventFunc()

    return dispatch({
        type: "USER_UPDATE",
        payload: {
            name,
            email,
            description,
        },
    });
};
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -2):

Have you connected redux with your component using connect method?